# Decomposing Into Real Representations

Tags: representation-theory

Decompose the regular representation of $C^3$ into irreducible real representations.
Since $C^3$ is abelian,thus all its complex irreducible representations must be one dimensional.I guess that its real irreducible representations 
should consist of some two dimensional subspaces also,but I am unable to do all this rigorously.Thanks for any help.